# Expected } at the end of input

Tags: arduino-uno

I am getting the error in my title when I try to compile the following code:

```
#define char incomingByte; //Defines incomingByte 
#define char sendBack = K;
#define char ?;
#define pollTime;

bool running = true;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600); //Set data rate.
}

void loop() {
for(Serial.available() > 0;)  { //Gets you the number of bytes that are available to be read from the serial port.
pollTime = delayMicroseconds(200); // Sets a poll time of 200 microseconds.
incomingByte  = Serial.read();
if(incomingByte = ?) {
Serial.print(sendBack);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is completely wrong in almost every respect.

---

```
#define char incomingByte; //Defines incomingByte
```

That line means that the compiler will substitute `incomingByte;` whenever it sees `char`.

---

```
#define char sendBack = K;
```

Now it will substitute `sendBack = K;` when it sees `char`.

---

```
#define char ?;
```

Now it will substitute `?;` when it sees `char`.

---

```
#define pollTime;
```

I don't know what you are thinking here. If you are trying to *declare* a variable you have to give a type, like this:

```
int pollTime;
```

---

```
bool running = true;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600); //Set data rate.
}
void loop() {
```

Those lines are OK.

---

```
for(Serial.available() > 0;)  { //Gets you the number of bytes that are available to be read from the serial port.
```

You don't want the semicolon there. A `for` loop is not written like that. You possibly mean `while`, ie.

```
while(Serial.available() > 0)
```

---

```
pollTime = delayMicroseconds(200); // Sets a poll time of 200 microseconds.
```

That is doing nothing of the sort. It is delaying 200 µs, it isn't setting anything.

---

```
incomingByte  = Serial.read();
```

That line is OK, assuming you declared `incomingByte` like this, and not the way you did:

```
char incomingByte;
```

---

```
if(incomingByte = ?) {
```

That needs to be in single quotes, as you are comparing a character. Also you compare with `==` not `=` ie.

```
if(incomingByte == '?') {
```

---

```
Serial.print(sendBack);
```

It looks from your earlier code you mean:

```
Serial.print('K');
```

---

```
  }
 }
}
```

These lines look OK.

---

I suggest you read a beginners page about C programming. This is just pure guesswork what you are doing here. For one thing, read up on how `#define` works. Here is one page: https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/constants/create_define.php. And another: http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/define.html

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. I'll look into the links that you provided.

Comment: P.S. you should change "respect" to "aspect" in the first line

Comment: I'm not sure about that. See [in all respects](http://www.wordreference.com/synonyms/in%20all%20respects) which means: *entirely, outright, wholly, thoroughly, altogether, totally, utterly*

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]

Try this:

```
int question = 63; //in the ascii table, ? is 63

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //set baud rate.
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available())  { //Gets you the number of bytes that are available to be read from the serial port.
    if (Serial.read() == question) {
      Serial.println("OK");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I run the code it gives the following error:

Comment: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]

Comment: refresh the page and test the new code

Comment: Thank you. This part worked. I forgot to mention that I also need it to turn off the LED if the condition is not met. When I run the code you have provided the LED is on.

Comment: There's really no reason to use the ascii code for a question mark here, it makes the program hard to understand.  Use `'?'`your earlier error was a result of using a string (double quotes) rather than a single character (single quotes).

Comment: "When I run the code you have provided the LED is on" - your question was nothing to do with LEDs, nor does your code make any attempt to turn them on or off.